# windows store app development using visual studio 2013 in windows 7 operating system

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

i want to develop windows store apps by using visual studio 2013 in windows 7 operating system.I know that this task is possible if i am using windows 8.1 operating system.but can anyone tell if this is possible with windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 7, you need to use VS 2010 (full or express version) to develop for WindowsPhone7 .

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/0e40579d-12a5-4aba-81cb-ab83e5956fc2/windows-7-visual-studio-2012-windows-phone-development?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: so you mean to say there is no way of using the below combination"windows 7 +VS 2013 +windows store app development".but unfortunately i end up installing VS 2013 in my Win7 OS.

Comment: Err... what? The OP asked about doing Windows Store apps (in other words, Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 apps, not Phone 7/8/8.1 apps) in Windows 7....